# Can't get the "div" in PlaceHolder in ASP.NET GridView ItemTemplate

Tags: javascript, asp.net, gridview

I have "PlaceHolder" in asp.net gridview, and in that placeholder i want to add dropdownlist with multiple selection. In codebehind i add a div to contain "Checkboxes", so when the user clicks the dropdown div will be open with checkboxes. But in javascript, i can't get the div by using grid.getElementById.

Here is the codebehind to create dropdown with checkboxes:

```
DropDownList ddl = new DropDownList();
        ddl.ID = "ddlChkList";
        ListItem lstItem = new ListItem();
        ddl.Items.Insert(0, lstItem);
        ddl.Width = new Unit(155);
        ddl.Attributes.Add("onmousedown", "showdivonClick()");
        CheckBoxList chkBxLst = new CheckBoxList();
        chkBxLst.ID = "chkLstItem";
        chkBxLst.Attributes.Add("onmouseover", "showdiv()");

        //DataTable dtListItem = ListPrograms();

        //int rowNo = dtListItem.Rows.Count;
        int rowCount = programs.Count;
        string lstValue = string.Empty;
        string lstID = string.Empty;

        int i = 0;

        foreach (AlmsPrograms program in programs)
        {
            i++;
            lstValue = program.PROGRAMNAME;
            lstID = program.PROGRAMID.ToString();
            lstItem = new ListItem("<a href=\"javascript:void(0)\" id=\"alst\" style=\"text-decoration:none;color:Black; \" onclick=\"getSelectedItem(' " + lstValue + "','" + i + "','" + lstID + "','anchor');\">" + lstValue + "</a>", program.PROGRAMID.ToString());
            lstItem.Attributes.Add("onclick", "getSelectedItem('" + lstValue + "','" + i + "','" + lstID + "','listItem');");
            chkBxLst.Items.Add(lstItem);
        }

        System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlGenericControl div = new System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlGenericControl("div");
        div.ID = "divChkList";
        div.Controls.Add(chkBxLst);
        div.Style.Add("border", "black 1px solid");
        div.Style.Add("width", "250px");
        div.Style.Add("height", "180px");
        div.Style.Add("overflow", "AUTO");
        div.Style.Add("display", "none");
        phDDLCHK.Controls.Add(ddl);
        phDDLCHK.Controls.Add(div);
```

Then in aspx file, i try to get that div with this code:

```
function showdivonClick() {
            var gridViewCtID = '<%=gvProgramSelection.ClientID %>';

            var grid = document.getElementById(gridViewCtID);
            var objDLL = document.getElementById(gridViewCtID + "_divChkList");
            //var objDLL = grid.getElementById('divChkList');
            if (objDLL.style.display == "block")
                objDLL.style.display = "none";
            else
                objDLL.style.display = "block";
        }
```

But the grid also adds "ctl01","ctl02" before "divChkList". How can i get these dynamically created names?

Thanks.

Comment: http://weblogs.asp.net/asptest/archive/2009/01/06/asp-net-4-0-clientid-overview.aspx

Comment: ClientIDMode solved it, thanks a lot...

Answer (score 0):

Set the ClientIDMode to Static which won't muck around with your id (but will still muck around with the name) or another quick and easy way is to just add a class to the div and use that as the selector in jQuery instead.

Comment: The `ClientIDMode` property will only be available if he's using the .Net Framework 4.0.

Comment: @Marcus That's why I've given two options